# Polynomial Regression: polynomial expansion

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm training a multivariate linear regression model using sklearn. All good. However, I'm struggling to understand the math underneath it when using training examples with several features. Concretely, I'd like to know if there is a general polynomial equation that resolves for any feature size vectors. The first equation on [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates) shows the generalized equation when x is a single number. How do I extrapolate this when x is, for instance, a 3-element vector?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043277/order-of-coefficients-in-polynomial-linear-regression) is a practical example of what I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [general linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model), which includes special cases like simple and multiple linear regression, ANOVA models, polynomial regression, etc. The general form is $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}$, where $\mathbf{Y}$ is the vector of responses, $\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix (containing all the terms without the coefficients), $\boldsymbol\beta$ is the vector containing the coefficients, and $\boldsymbol\varepsilon$ is the vector of random errors satisfying $E(\boldsymbol\varepsilon) = \mathbf{0}, Var(\boldsymbol\varepsilon) =\sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$.

Written out in full, your RGB model would look like something like this:

$ \begin{bmatrix} y_1\\ y_2\\ y_3 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & r_1 & g_1 & b_1 & r_1^2 & g_1^2 & b_1^2 & r_1g_1 & r_1b_1 & g_1b_1 \\  
1 & r_2 & g_2 & b_2 & r_2^2 & g_2^2 & b_2^2 & r_2g_2 & r_2b_2 & g_2b_2 \\  
1 & r_3 & g_3 & b_3 & r_3^2 & g_3^2 & b_3^2 & r_3g_3 & r_3b_3 & g_3b_3 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\  
1 & r_n & g_n & b_n & r_n^2 & g_n^2 & b_n^2 & r_ng_n & r_nb_n & g_nb_n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0\\ \beta_1\\ \beta_2\\ \beta_3 \\ \beta_4 \\ \beta_5 \\ \beta_6 \\ \beta_7 \\ \beta_8 \\ \beta_9 \\ \beta_{10} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_1\\ \varepsilon_2\\ \varepsilon_3 \\ \vdots \\ \varepsilon_n \end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: Thank you. But what rule have you follow to get the X matrix? what if I was trying to fit an n order polynomial?

Comment: Just put one term without the coefficient in each column, like in the RGB example.

Comment: I get that, my question is: why the 8th column is r*g and not, for instance, g*b? what rule do you follow to come up with the : 1, r^2, g^2, b^2, rg, rb,gb order ?

Comment: The order isn't important. You're adding everything together in the end; addition of reals is commutative, so it doesn't change anything...